# Poisson process (simple question)

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Imagine you have two events starting at the same time. The duration time for each event is exponential, with different parameters. Knowing that one of the events is finished (we don't know which) at instant *t*, how does one get the distribution of the time between *t* and the moment the other event ends?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the parameters of the exponentials $X$ and $Y$ be $a$ and $b$. Think of them as the lifetimes of two components. We will assume that at some time $t$, we test the system and discover that precisely one of the components is dead.

This has probability $(1-e^{-ta})e^{-tb}+(1-e^{-tb})e^{-ta}$. The (conditional) probability that it is $X$ is 
$$\frac{(1-e^{-ta})e^{-tb}}{(1-e^{-ta})e^{-tb}+(1-e^{-tb})e^{-ta}}.$$
There is a similar expression for the probability it is $Y$.
If it is $X$, then by memorylessness, the probability that the additional time is $\le s$ is $1-e^{-sb}$. If it is $Y$, then the probability is $1-e^{-sa}$. Now one puts the pieces together.